# Co-variate contribution to model accuracy in multi-variate analysis

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, univariate

I have implemented a multivariate analysis in R as such:

```
lm1<-lm(Y ~ A + B + C + D + E, data=data, weights = 1/Uncert)
```

I found that the variable A contributes a lot in explaining Y variability in the multivariate analysis (up to 25%). In addition, whenever I remove the variable A to the multivariate analysis, the performance of my model decreases significantly. However, if I perform an uni-variate analysis, there is a very low correlation between my independent variable A and my dependent variable Y. Therefore, my question is to know whether it is statistically possible that a variable showing a very low correlation with a response Y in an uni-variate analysis become an important variable in explaining Y variability in a multivariate analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a relationship that holds true within certain groups but not across. 
In this case your model will have a very good fit if you ensure the groups are controlled for, then also the variable corresponding to this relationship will have a lot of explanatory power.

*Example*:
lets assume you observe an outcome $yo$ jointly with a continuous feature $x$ for two groups:
[image]

Now you try to assess the link between $yo$ and $x$, using linear regression (i.e. just looking at the unconditional correlation). Because you neglect the information that they belong to two groups, your model-fit will be really bad.
[image]
If you control for the groups (e.g. by adding group-dummies as control variables), your model fit will be a lot better, and the role of $x$ will become apparent
[image]